# How to implement jQuery to PHP or how to get javascript-proceeded output of html page?

Tags: php, jquery

jQuery has some awsome methods, that I could really use while working with external htmls is there a way to somehow transform it into a PHP framework ?

**EDIT**: Many people missunderstood the question purpose - of course I know PHP's DOM but the real purpose was to be able to do same syntax (and use same methods) in PHP while working with external htmls.

**EDIT2:** possible solution would be something like get html string, add a jQuery string to it and somehow make PHP to get the javascript-processed output ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? jQuery is made to provide an easy to use interface to manipulate the DOM. There is no DOM in PHP context, unless you are working on a XML document in which case there are libraries to handle this.

Comment: You can use jQuery in your PHP-generated HTML...

Comment: @roasted what has node to do with this question?

Comment: @YotamOmer did i misread the question, maybe...

Comment: Nothing. jQuery manipulates an EXISTING dom, PHP/NodeJS generate it.

Comment: @dystroy it specifics need of adding the whole framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traversal methods based on the CSS3 selector syntax has been replicated in PHPQuery.

> https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ is is a server-side, chainable,
>   CSS3 selector driven Document Object Model (DOM) API based on jQuery
>   JavaScript Library.

It's quite neat if you need to manipulate and query DOM structures, though in my experience it was quite slow.

Comment: Yes this is kind of what I was looking for and since nobody else is providing a better answer, i will choose it as a correct answer :) Thank you for answering my question and not just complaining about JS doesnt beloning in PHP :) Again, big thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

For the selector part in jQuery, phpQuery is the way to go.
https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Anri offtopic comment....

Answer (score 0):

jQuery functions mainly deal with :

- browser specifics, that depends on the browser and thus don't make sense server side
- dynamic DOM manipulation, and you don't have access server side to the browser DOM
- browser event handling, that... well, you get the picture...

So not only would it be hard to do, but, as "described" in your question, it wouldn't make any kind of sense.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery isn't designed to do anything that PHP typically does... so why would you want to use it in PHP?

If you want to manipulate/scrape HTML documents I can recommend the [DOM class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).